# Adding third party application dependency in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#-4.0

In my application their is a requirement of **.net framework 4.5** to run it properly on other machine. 
How it is possible that when my application is being install then .net framework is installed automatically?

Answer (score 2):

You can set in dependency by adding the reference of .Net 4.0 Framework.

Comment: I already tried this but there is a problem that .net framework is opening its own installer. If there is a way yo install it automatically without using separate installation.

Answer (score -1):

Did you check it by making .dll of third party applcation and referenced to you active application?